# Granted scope of publishing permissions via Facebook Open Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there an API to read which setting the user has selected in the second step of the popup? i.e.: "Friends", "Only me", Public", ...

[image: Login]

Comment: No, not directly – you can only check after a post was made through your app, what the privacy settings for that particular post were. And the fact you’re asking makes me suspect that you want to do something like rewarding users for public posts or similar – which would be against Platform Policies, so please don't do it.